# Замена части значения константы

Tags: php, replace

Имеется константа с плавающими значениями внутри, которые могут быть изменены.
К примеру:

```
const I_DESCR = 'Дверь открывается в 8:00. Закрываем ее в 18:00';
echo I_DESCR;
```

Текст замены здесь: 8:00 и 18:00.
Стало быть, следует писать:

```
const I_DESCR   = 'Дверь открывается в %first. Закрываем ее в %second';
```

и чем-то последовательно заменять все это при выводе.

Подскажите, чем можно тут воспользоваться для такой замены?

Comment: `str_replace();`

Comment: можно регуляркой вынуть имена и поменять.

Comment: [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) это то, что вы хотите сделать. Пример: `sprintf('Дверь открывается в %s. Закрываем ее в %s', '8:00', '18:00')`

Comment: Вопрос не очевиден. Выбор ответа будет зависеить от того, откуда вы будете брать значения для подстановки. Если, например, из массива 1[ first=>'8:00, second=>'22:00], то нужна регулярка.... и тп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует воспользоваться функцией [sprintf](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

```
const I_DESCR = 'Дверь открывается в %s. Закрываем ее в %s';

...

sprintf(self::I_DESCR, '8:00', '18:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TEMPLATE = 'Дверь открывается в %first. Закрываем ее в %second';
$output = str_replace(['%first', '%second',], ['8.00', '18.00',], TEMPLATE);
```